# swift 3: How to hide status bar without losing height

Tags: swift, xcode, height, hide, statusbar

When I hide the status bar in one page from the uipageviewcontroller then move the whole content up.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

[Show images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXIUW.png)

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the top constraint to `Top Layout Guide` instead of `View` in interface builder. Like so

[image]

`Top Layout Guide` will be based on the status bar (or phone call, etc.) Where view will be a static value ignoring if the view has a status bar or not.